# How to zip a file and send over HTTP without writing to disk or loading the full file in memory?

Tags: c#, http, stream, .net-core

My requirement is to upload a file in zip format to a certain destination.

- The file needs to be HTTP POSTed to the destination as a zip file
- The POST has to be a multipart message containing additional data (which I think is irrelevant to my question)
- **The solution is in .Net Core**

I have some working code; however, this requires me to copy the input stream onto a memory stream for zipping, thus loading the full file in memory.

This becomes an issue when the file is bigger than the available memory, causing my process to end due to OOM.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace HttpZipPipe
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string sourceUrl = "https://aacapps.com/lamp/sound/amy.wav";
        private const string destUrl = "http://httpbin.org/post";    

        public static Stream CreateZipStream(Stream inputStream, string zipEntryName)
        {
            var zipStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(zipEntryName);
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                    inputStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
            }
            zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return zipStream;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String responseMessage;
            var Client = new HttpClient();

            using (var httpStream = Client.GetStreamAsync(sourceUrl).Result)
            using (var zipStream = CreateZipStream(httpStream, "audio.wav"))
            using (var fileContent = new StreamContent(zipStream))
            {  
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(fileContent, "file", "file.zip");
                // ignored additional content and headers for clarity...
                responseMessage = Client.PostAsync(destUrl, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is what's going on in the "CreateZipStream" method, in particular this:

```
inputStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
```

I suspect that this is causing my process to go OOM.

Is there a way to pipe the input stream via a zip stream to the content without having to copy the full thing in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to use your service so I used a regular web app to use the `Response` to test with but something like this should work. You'll have to read and write at the same time.

I also used `SharpZipLib` found as a `nuget` package.

For the file you'll have to add boundaries and filename to the data (multipart message as you added in the SO). There are some SO posts on how to do that.

```
// Create the request
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://aacapps.com/lamp/sound/amy.wav");
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

var size = 1024 * 8;
var buffer = new byte[size];

// Create a POST request
// The four next rows I haven't tested but it's a regular POST you'll need to do
var sq = WebRequest.Create("http://httpbin.org/post");
sq.Method = "POST";
sq.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

// Get the stream to write to
using (var res = sq.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Create zip using the httpbin request stream as writer
    using (var zip = new ZipOutputStream(res))
    {
        zip.SetLevel(3);

        // Create file entry
        var entry = new ZipEntry(ZipEntry.CleanName("amy.wav"));
        zip.PutNextEntry(entry);

        // Get the data stream
        using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            int numBytes;
            // Read the data until no more
            while ((numBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
            {
                // Write to the zip file buffer
                zip.Write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
        }
        zip.Close();
    }
}

// Didn't try these either but it's just reading the result if any
var resp = sq.GetResponse();
new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My concern is that this code: `while ((numBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
            {
                zip.Write(buffer, 0, size);
            }` will keep filling the buffer in memory before the response is sent. In short, this does not seem to do a 'piping' as I would want to.

Comment: No, buffer is only `1024 * 8`. The data is sent on the stream directly.

Comment: As you can see there is no file or other places where the data is stored. Think how it writes to disk; The file would grow as the data is compressed in `1024 * 8` chunks and put into the file stream. It just so happens that it's now a network stream.